# ROS for raspberry pi OS 2021 (using raspberry pi 4, 8GB)?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I need to know if there is any ROS distribution version for raspberry pi OS 2021 (using raspberry pi 4, 8GB) because I need to use ROS LIDAR SICK with this OS. (I used noetic on ubuntu 20.04, but it doesn't work well on raspberry OS)
I appreciate your help,

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/389984/ros-for-raspberry-pi-os-2021-(using-raspberry-pi-4,-8gb)?/) by [julius82](https://answers.ros.org/users/88819/julius82/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2021-11-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello @julius82,

> I used noetic on ubuntu 20.04

If you are using Noetic, try to use noetic in raspberry pi because your communication will be easier and connection establishment will be easy with the same distribution.

You can have a look below are some ways to install noetic into Raspberry pi 4.

You can directly put the ROS Noetic into the Raspberry Pi OS.

You can have a look at the below steps for [installing](https://varhowto.com/install-ros-noetic-raspberry-pi-4/).

Or else, you can directly install ubuntu [20.04 into your raspberry 4](https://ubuntu.com/download/raspberry-pi) and directly install noetic in it.

---

Originally posted by [Ranjit Kathiriya](https://answers.ros.org/users/63046/ranjit-kathiriya/) with karma: 1622 on 2021-11-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0